# Can Digizuite for Sitecore be configured to be closed for public access

Tags: media-library

Is it possible to configure `Digizuite for Sitecore (DFS)` to be closed to the public and only accessible by a `Sitecore CD server` (and any other necessary clients)? We would like to force all assets (images, PDFs, etc) to be served only from the Sitecore CD server.

AFAIK images get stored in the regular Sitecore file system media cache, but other media such as PDFs do not.